# How to edit PostgreSQL tables with a uuid primary key using IntelliJ's database Table Editor?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, uuid, pycharm

I have hooked-up PyCharm with my PostgreSQL database. All of my tables have a `uuid` column as their primary key. When I attempt to edit a row's value, I get the following error:

```
[2014-03-05 17:31:08] UPDATE "iv"."user" SET "active" = ? WHERE "id" = ?
[2014-03-05 17:31:08] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 49
```

When I edit a column value in a table with an `integer` primary key, the change saves properly, so I am sure it is an issue with the `uuid` primary key. Does anyone know how to get this to work? My co-worker is having this issue with IntelliJ Ultimate as well, so I'm assuming it is a problem with all IntelliJ products.

Comment: It looks like this is a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104501) on the JetBrains issue tracker. Almost a year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Gregory Shrago at JetBrains.  He fixed the issue and it should be available in the latest Early Access Preview.  The bug status is updated here:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104501